# Does GCloud SQL charges grow with increase in data?

Tags: gcloud

I am getting higher bills as each month passes that I am considering moving completely away from GCloud SQL.
Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL: Zonal - Small instance in Seoul(₩42,840)
Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL: Zonal - Standard storage in Seoul(₩30,080)
HTTP Load Balancing: Global Forwarding Rule Minimum Service Charge(₩23,751)

(No backup is even enabled for the instance)

That's up to $100 with little or no traffic yet! I don't see this as viable.
My question is, does the cost just keep going up with data and with traffic?

Comment: Google Cloud provides pricing calculators so that you can determine your costs. All cloud vendors charge based upon storage, network bandwidth, service infrastructure, etc. Only you can decide if a service provides good value for your use case.

Comment: Thanks. I used the calculator, but the estimates there always seem so far off :)